# Preloaded radio button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

i am trying to have one of three radio buttons checked, when the page loads and if that happen, i want to make some actions
There is the java code

```
if (variable.equals("D"))
{
top.setVariable("{varA}", "checked='checked'");
}else if (variable.equals("R"))
{
top.setVariable("{varB}", "checked='checked'");
}else if (variable.equals("A"))
{
top.setVariable("{varC}", "checked='checked'");
}
```

And then, this is the html code

```
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="D"" {varA}/>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="R"" {varB}/>
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="A"" {varC}/>
```

I want to have when any of the radio button are checked, to hide or show some part of the pages when the page loads; something similar to this

```
    if($j("input[name='radio'][value='D']").attr('checked','checked'))
    {
    $j("#div1").show();
    $j("#div").hide();
    }
    else if($j("input[@name='radio'][value='A']").attr('checked','checked'))
        {
            $j("#div1").hide();
            $j("#div").show();
        }
```

But, i having some inconsistencies, and sometimes the right radio button is checked, and sometimes the wrong one, and obviously the wrong divs are shown

Any idea or solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: You have duplicate quotes at the ends of your inputs. Here's my alternate solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xzqmahpq/

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code.

Change this :

```
$j("input[@name='radio'][value='A']"
```

TO

```
$j("input[name='radio'][value='A']"
```

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake in the copy paste... but i have the right values on my code

Comment: No, the results are the same. I am doing the validation in $j(document).ready(function(){
to doing it when the page loads, but i don't know if the value is lost sometimes, or if the property checked isn't working properly

Comment: @jmoreira256, What version of jquery are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, mostly typos. I'd insert the Java variable directly as JS var, then use that to initialize the HTML.

```js
/*
JAVA code:
top.setVariable("{varDRA}", variable);
*/

// actual line you're going to use:
// var DRA = "{varDRA}";
// for demo purposes:
var DRA = "R";


$(document).ready(function() {
  // set event handler
  $("input[name=dra]").change(function() {
    $(".panel").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val() + "div").show();
  });

  // set active radio button
  $("input[name=dra]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == DRA) {
      this.checked = true; // check radio button
      $(this).change();  // call handler to show div
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="dra" type="radio" value="D">
<input name="dra" type="radio" value="R">
<input name="dra" type="radio" value="A">

<div id="Ddiv" class="panel">D div</div>
<div id="Rdiv" class="panel">R div</div>
<div id="Adiv" class="panel">A div</div>
```

Comment: One question, with your solution, the radio button will be checked when the page loads? I am asking, because i see the .change there

Comment: Yes, the `// set active radio button` part sets the proper button's `.checked` to `true`, then calls its `.change()` to show the associated `div`.